# Oracle, using window / rank feature to group rows

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query

```
Select SalesPerson.SalesPersonName, TimeTable.month,
sum(SalesPerson_sales) SUM_OF_SALES
From SalesPerson
Join SalesRecordTable on SalesRecordTable.SalesPerson_id=SalesPerson.SalesPerson_id
Join TimeTable on TimeTable.time_id = SalesRecordTable.time_id
Group by SalesPersonName , TimeTable.month  with rollup 
order by SalesPersonName
```

Which is producing

```
SalesPersonName month                        TotalSales
NULL             NULL                          565238.13
Andy             1                         15966.75
Andy             2                         10723.32
Andy             3                         17174.77
Andy             4                         9911.38
Andy             5                         12380.12
Andy             6                         12194.56
Andy             7                         18964.82
(more records not pasted here, it basically goes upto month 12, then the records for other sales people follow)
```

What I actually am trying to do is to get something like this

```
SalesPersonName month       TotalSales

Andy            3        71762
Andy            6        34486
Andy            9        31738
Andy            12       21532
John            3        23323
John            6         32873
```

Basically, I want to use the SQL OLAP features to sum each 3 months sales, per sales person and show it like above.

I am trying to use either the Range or the Rows clause, but I am missing something here :( like below

```
Select SalesPerson.SalesPersonName, TimeTable.month,
    sum(SalesPerson_sales) SUM_OF_SALES OVER ( order by month rows 2 preceding)
    From SalesPerson
    Join SalesRecordTable on SalesRecordTable.SalesPerson_id=SalesPerson.SalesPerson_id
    Join TimeTable on TimeTable.time_id = SalesRecordTable.time_id
    Group by SalesPersonName , TimeTable.month  with rollup 
    order by SalesPersonName
```

But this is giving me

```
SalesPersonName     month   (No column name)
Andy                1   1
Andy                    1   2.06
Andy                    1   3.14
Andy                    1   3.26
, thousands of records follow :(
```

how can I fix the query above to get the desired result? I think I need to fix the rows 2 preceding part somehow and it will work as needed.

many thanks for your input

Comment: You really don't need `ROLLUP`, analytic functions and other fancy things here. As mentioned in below answer `CEIL(month / 3)` is all what you need to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions, but instead, I think you could just `GROUP BY CEIL(month / 3)`.

Comment: thanks but I'd really like to just fix the rwos 2 preceding part